# how to define onChange function in input - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create inputs as dynamically. each of inputs have a `onChange` function with a variable.

all of my code:

```
var distinct_inputs = 0;
$('.icon1').click( function(){
  distinct_inputs = distinct_inputs + 1 ;
  $('#insert-file').append('<ul class="ul list-inline"><li style="width:90%"><input onchange="changePath('+distinct_inputs+')" type="file" class="base'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-base"><input  type="text" class="fake'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-fake" readonly placeholder="choose your file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open input-place"></span></li><li class="icon fa fa-minus"></li></ul>');
});

function changePath(distinct_inputs) {
  console.log(distinct_inputs);
}
```

But my inputs when changed I got this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: changePath is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (..
```

Comment: hahaha...keep the changePath out so it is registered in the DOM

Comment: @RohitasBehera Post it as answer with edited code.... that will help to the person

Comment: I have already posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `changePath` function as shown in below code. it will work.

```
var distinct_inputs = 0;
    $('.icon1').click( function(){
        distinct_inputs = distinct_inputs + 1 ;
        $('#insert-file').append('<ul class="ul list-inline"><li style="width:90%"><input onchange="changePath('+distinct_inputs+')" type="file" class="base'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-base"><input  type="text" class="fake'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-fake" readonly placeholder="choose your file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open input-place"></span></li><li class="icon fa fa-minus"></li></ul>');
    });

changePath = function(distinct_inputs)
    {
        console.log(distinct_inputs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to declare change path outside of Document ready.

See how it works here .. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function changePath(distinct_inputs)
    {
        console.log(distinct_inputs);
    }
    
     
$(document).ready(function(){

     
var distinct_inputs = 0;
    $('.icon1').click( function(){
        distinct_inputs = distinct_inputs + 1 ;
        $('#insert-file').append('<ul class="ul list-inline"><li style="width:90%"><input onchange="changePath('+distinct_inputs+')" type="file" class="base'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-base"><input  type="text" class="fake'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-fake" readonly placeholder="choose your file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open input-place"></span></li><li class="icon fa fa-minus"></li></ul>');
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="insert-file" ></div>
<button type="button" class="icon1">CLick here</button>

</body>
</html>
```